# Typo3 - remove default target in external menu item

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have the below typoscript

```
lib.nav = HMENU
lib.nav {
  wrap = <ul> | </ul>
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
        expAll=1
        NO {
        |*| <ul><li> | </li></ul> |*| <ul><li> | </li></ul> || <ul><li class="last"> | </li></ul> |*|

            wrapItemAndSub = |*| <li> | </li> |*| <li> | </li> || <li class="last"> | </li> |*|
            stdWrap.cObject = CASE
            stdWrap.cObject {
                key.field = doktype
                default = TEXT
                default.field = title
                default.typolink.parameter.data = field:uid
                default.typolink.ATagBeforeWrap=0
                3 < .default
                3 {
                stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
                typolink {
                parameter {
                data >
                dataWrap = http://{field:url}
            }
            }
        }
        }
          doNotLinkIt = 1     # to avoid "<a>" repeated twice
          subst_elementUid = 1
        }
      }
        2 = TMENU
      2 {
        expAll=1
        wrap = <ul> | </ul>
        NO {
          wrapItemAndSub =  |*| <li> | </li> |*| <li> | </li> || <li> | </li> |*|
          stdWrap.cObject = CASE
          stdWrap.cObject {
            key.field = doktype
            default = TEXT
            default.field = title
            default.typolink.parameter.data = field:uid
            default.typolink.ATagBeforeWrap=0
        3 < .default
        3 {
        stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        typolink {
        parameter {
        data >
        dataWrap = http://{field:url}
        }
        }
        }
          }
          doNotLinkIt = 1     # to avoid "<a>" repeated twice
          subst_elementUid = 1
        }
      }
    }
```

Which seems to work well, however I have notice a slight glitch when I have an external url page in the nav.  It generates the below code for an external url.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php?id=3">External Links</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a target="_top" href="http://example.com/1">Example 1</a></li>
        <li><a target="_top" href="http://example.com/2">Example 2</a></li>
        <li><a target="_top" href="http://example.com/3">Example 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

How do I remove this default setting? I want it to be configurable per page in the behaviour tab (link target field in LTS 4.5).

I also have the below set in my constants.

```
PAGE_TARGET = 
content.pageFrameObj =
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set in setup the extTarget via [config](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.7.0/view/1/6/#id1556666). It is default "_top".

```
# just set it to an empty string instead of _top
config.extTarget =
```

Comment: this has removed the target="_top" thanks.  Do you have any idea from the description I gave in the question as to why the content of the Link Target field still isn't being read?  I have put in _blank but nothing appeared.  I then tried putting _blank in the url field eg www.example.com _blank and this worked.

Comment: Maybe a bug? Please check again with a fresh installation and report a bug if the setting is not respected. But please double check your configuration beforehand.